# Time Field only in Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365

Can anyone suggest me how to use Time only Field in a List of `SharePoint`

[image]

Comment: for just display time add calculated field see [format dateTime](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7afdbe60-c294-4b42-9241-2398da2d4137/display-time-only-in-the-date-field-column?forum=sharepointgeneral)

Comment: see [http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31346/custom-sharepoint-list-xml-field-timeonly](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31346/custom-sharepoint-list-xml-field-timeonly)